# Is it possible to configure a Serilog Sub-logger from appSettings

Tags: serilog

This is what I am doing now:

```
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
            .WriteTo.Logger(l => l.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Matching.WithProperty("XXX")).WriteTo.File("output.txt"))
            .CreateLogger();
```

I have my main Logger set up in app.config, but I can't figure out the syntax for specifying a sub-logger there. I'd really like to avoid mixing code and appSettings configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this isn't possible using Serilog as it is today.

Comment: Update: v2 will have this, using custom setting prefixes. `WriteTo.AppSettings(prefix: "sub")` will read from keys `"sub:serilog:..."` allowing the sub-logger to be uniquely configured.

Comment: Nicholas, will it be possible, in v2, to _add_ sublogger via AppSettings?